# How to store the values of a JuMP variable to a nested dictionary in julia

Tags: dictionary, julia, julia-jump

After I optimize I would like to store parts of a 4 dimensional variable array to a nested dictionary. Is there a way to do this?

My array `inventory` looks like this:

```
4-dimensional DenseAxisArray{VariableRef,4,...} with index sets:
    Dimension 1, ["P1", "P2"]
    Dimension 2, ["AMS", "BOM", "BSL", "BWI", "CDG", "CPHA", "DUBA", "FCO", "GRU", "HND"  …  "MXP", "NRT", "PHL", "QWU", "RCS", "SIN", "SJU", "TLV", "VIE", "YYZ"]
    Dimension 3, ["USx", "halfEURO", "EUROx", "XLx", "TWINx"]
    Dimension 4, ["g", "b"]
```

I want a nested dictionary only of `P2` and `g` that looks like this:

```
a = Dict("AMS" => Dict("USx"=>[value], "halEURO"=>[value], … ))
```

I tried to do it in a for loop but I failed.

Thank you for any kind of help!

Comment: What is `[value]` supposed to represent?

Comment: I meant a placeholder with [value] for the integer value that for example inventory["P1","AMS","USx","g"] takes while optimization.